# Си: проблема с getchar() и EOF(^Z) в Windows консоли

Tags: c, windows, консоль, io

Уже очень долгое время пытаюсь понять:

Почему цикл не завершается, если я введу "dfkjsdf^Z", в то время как при
"dfkjsdf (**тут я нажимаю Enter**) ^Z" - завершается? То есть, как сделать так, чтобы он вышел из цикла, если я нажимаю *CTRL+Z* до того, как нажму *Enter*

Это, пожалуй, самое непонятное для меня в языке Си. И сколько бы я не рылся в гугле, ответа все же найти не смог..

```
int main() {
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    int arr[10];
    while((arr[i] = getchar()) != EOF && i < 10) {
        printf("arr[i] is %c\n",arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То есть вы набираете на клавиатуре `dfkjsdf^Z` без Enter'а? И да, какая у вас система, и какая консоль? Обработка ^Z зависит от консоли.

Comment: Это поведение не языка Си, а виндоус консоли (переходите в \*nix)

Comment: Да. То есть я ввожу `dfkjsdf`, затем `CTRL+Z`, затем `Enter`.  Windows 10.
 cmd

Comment: @avp: Чем тут должен помочь "переход в *nix"? Логика `Ctrl-D` в *nix отличается в деталях, но внешне она похожа. При построчной буферизации конец файла возникает только при нажатии `Ctrl-D` на пустом буфере, то есть нажимать `Enter` перед `Ctrl-D` придется и там.

Comment: @AnT,  в родном для языка окружении проще учиться (и вообще ...)

Comment: @AnT, `то есть нажимать Enter перед Ctrl-D придется и там` -- как раз нет. (хотел ответить сразу, но решил все же проверить). ^D после `Enter` сразу дает EOF. ^D после ввода символов отправляет эти символы в программу (естественно, без передачи ^D, \n, \r или чего-то подобного). Поэтому ввод подряд двух ^D после ввода символов завершает stdin без всякой потери данных.

Comment: @avp:  Окружение *nix является неродным для С еще со времен ранней стандартизации. Учиться там сложнее именно потому, что есть опасность набраться "родных" привычек, которые на самом деле никакого отношения к настоящему С не имеют и были выжжены из языка каленым железом еще во времена динозавров. Сегодня нередко приходится тратить довольно много времени на переучивание упертых жертв обучения в "родной" среде.

Comment: @avp: Автор вопроса жалуется именно на необходимость нажатия `Enter` *перед* нажатием `Ctrl-Z`, т.е. именно на необходимость того, чтобы входной буфер в этот момент бы пустым. *nix накладывает на `Ctrl-D` в точности то же самое требование. Никакой разницы тут нет. То, что в  `Ctrl-D` в *nix само по себе проталкивает входной буфер, не требуя дополнительного нажатия `Enter` роли уже не играет - вопрос не об этом финальном нажатии `Enter`.

Comment: @AnT, на самом деле автор хочет ---  `как сделать так, чтобы он вышел из цикла, если я нажимаю CTRL+Z до того, как нажму Enter`. Насколько я понимаю, он **не хочет**, чтобы `\n` ему попадался. В \*nix он это получает, так сказать, "из коробки"

Comment: @AnT: Мне показалось, что автор просто *"хочет понять"*, как он сам сказал. Я вижу конкретный вопрос "Почему цикл не завершается, если я введу "dfkjsdf^Z", в то время как при "dfkjsdf (тут я нажимаю Enter) ^Z" - завершается?" Именно это поведение идентично в Windows и *nix. Именно на этот вопрос я и отвечал.

Comment: Разобравшись в теме с вашей помощью, хочу пояснить вопрос: если я через getchar()  *сначала* введу символы, *затем* нажму ctrl + z, *а затем* enter. Как выйти из цикла? Какой вывод все же напрашивается: ctrl + z, введенный после символов, принимает не EOF, а SUB (26 по аскии). Поэтому если я в `while` припишу `(c != 26)`, то последовательность "jksdfkj^Z*`(ENTER)`*" будет завершать цикл, чего не добиться при прошлом условии `while ((c = getchar) != EOF)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это не имеет никакого отношения к языку С, а зависит только от алгорима обработки комбинации <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> консолью Windows и интерпретацией результатов этой обработки той реализацией стандартной библиотеки, которую вы используете.

Ввод в Windows терминале буферизуется построчно. При этом обработка присутствующих в буфере символов `^Z` следует довольно запутанному алгоритму (по крайней мере при использовании стантартной библиотеки из комплекта MSVC).

- Комбинация <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> сама по себе не вызывает "проталкивания" накопленного буфера на выход (в отличие от комбинации <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> в Linux). Она лишь добавляет во входной буфер символ `^Z`, т.е. `\x1a`. Вы можете нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> несколько раз, помещая во входной буфер несколько символов `^Z`. После этого вы можете продолжать вводить что-то еще. Чтобы все-таки послать накопленный буфер ожидающему процессу, придется нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Если входной буфер содержит какие-то символы до первого появления символа `^Z`, то ожидающий ввода процесс увидит все эти символы, после чего процесс увидит один символ `^Z`, т.е. `\x1a`. Это будет просто символ `\x1a`. Никакой ситуации "конец файла" при этом не возникнет. Однако остаток входного буфера (после первого символа `^Z`) процессу виден не будет, как будто его и не было.

  То есть если вы введете в Windows терминале последовательность `abc^Z^Zdef^Zghi` и нажмете <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то на вход ваш процесс получит символы `a`, `b`, `c` и `\x1a`. Весь остальной ввод пропадет бесследно. Заметьте, что при этом "пропадает" и символ перевода строки, cгенерированный нажатием <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Если входной буфер сразу же начинается с символа `^Z`, то входной буфер считается пустым. Все его содержимое пропадает, не происходит даже чтения символа `^Z`. Возникает ситуация "конец файла".

  То есть если вы введете в Windows терминале последовательность `^Zdef` и нажмете <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то на вход ваш процесс не получит вообще ничего. Вместо этого функция ввода сообщит вам, что наткнулась на конец файла.

Поэтому для того, чтобы создать в буферизованном консольном вводе ситуацию "конец файла" придется вводить `^Z` в самом начале новой строки.

---

Если вам нужна посимвольная обработка входа, то можно предварительно отключить построчную буферизацию ввода

```
HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD dwMode;
GetConsoleMode(hIn, &dwMode);
dwMode &= ~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;
SetConsoleMode(hIn, dwMode);
```

В таком варианте каждый введенный символ будет немедленно читаться вашей `getchar()` и символ `^Z` будет немедленно интерпретироваться как конец файла.

Comment: Спасибо! Я многое понял теперь. Получается, что: _Конец файла_ (EOF) - это _пустой буфер_. Как его получить? - Вызвав `getchar()`, сразу же нажать `CTRL+Z` и отправить процессору (нажав _Enter_).

Comment: Что такое getchar()? Это дочерний процесс, который ставит на паузу родительский процесс, т.е. _присваивание_ (char c **=** getchar()), и копит в буфере символы; когда мы нажимаем Enter, мы завершаем дочерний процесс , следовательно _присваивание_ снимается  с паузы и забрасываем _туда_ буфер, возвращенный процессом getchar(). Если буфер вернулся пустым - это EOF. Если в буфере хотя бы что-нибудь есть, то это не конец файла, это последовательность символов, в конце которой - 'x1a'.